# How can I use @JsonView / @JsonBackReference / @JsonIdentityInfo to serialize desired child elements depending on scenario

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Consider having DTOs like this

```
@Data
class Profile {
    @JsonView({Profile.Views.Simple.class, Views.AllFields.class})
    String name;
    @JsonView(Profile.Views.AllFields.class)
    Collection<Image> images;
    static class Views {
        static class Simple {
        }
        static class AllFields {
        }
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Image {
    @JsonView({Image.Views.Simple.class,Profile.Views.AllFields.class})
    String name;
    @JsonView(Image.Views.AllFields.class)
    Profile profile;
    static class Views {
        static class Simple {
        }
        static class AllFields {
        }
    }
}
```

I can imagine quite simple scenario, that depending on what is the root of the operation, I would like to have JSON output of root entities with the first level of related objects eg.

fetching Users

```
{
  name: userName,
  images: [
    {
      name: image1Name
    }
  ]
}
```

or when fetching images

```
{
  name: imageName,
  user: {
    name: userName
  }
}
```

Is is possible to use some sort of @JsonView trick, or do I have to create seprate DTOs for different scenarios?

Jackson ObjectMapper seems to be able to handle only single class view, thus attempt like

```
Profile p = new Profile();
p.setName("ProfileName");

p.setImages(Arrays.asList(new Image("ImageName1", p), new Image("ImageName", p)))
System.out.println(mapper
                .writerWithView(Profile.Views.AllFields.class)
                .withView(Image.Views.Simple.class)
                .writeValueAsString(p));
        System.out.println(mapper
                .writerWithView(Profile.Views.Simple.class)
                .withView(Image.Views.Simple.class)
                .writeValueAsString(p.getImages().iterator().next()));
```

results in empty jsons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson is kind of magic (when it works the way you want).
**First problem** is to solve the infinite recursion due to cyclic dependency using `@JsonIdentityInfo`.
**Second problem** is to hide specific fields while serializing respective beans using `@JsonView`.

**`Profile.java`**

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "name")
class Profile {

    String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Profile.class)
    Collection<Image> images;

    // setter getter or lombok annotations
}
```

**`Image.java`**

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "name")
class Image {

    String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Image.class)
    Profile profile;

    // constructor, setter getter or lombok annotations
}
```

**`Views.java`**

```
class Views {
    public static class Profile {}
    public static class Image {}
}
```

And Finally **`Main.java`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Profile p1 = new Profile();
    p1.setName("ProfileName1");

    Profile p2 = new Profile();
    p2.setName("ProfileName2");

    Image image1 = new Image("ImageName1", p1);
    Image image2 = new Image("ImageName2", p2);

    p1.setImages(Arrays.asList(image1, image2));

    String json = mapper
            .writerWithView(Views.Profile.class)
            .writeValueAsString(p1);
    System.out.println(json);

    json = mapper.
            writerWithView(Views.Image.class)
            .writeValueAsString(image1);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**`Output:`**

```
// p1
{
  "name": "ProfileName1",
  "images": [
    {
      "name": "ImageName1"
    },
    {
      "name": "ImageName2"
    }
  ]
}

// image1
{
  "name": "ImageName1",
  "profile": {
    "name": "ProfileName1"
  }
}
```